# Is it possible to play a ssm:// on Android?

Tags: android, broadcast, mms

everyone

I'm, trying to play a ssm stream on Android.
However, I tried many ways, I can't find how to do it.
Is there any better way to do it?

This is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
    try {
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://xxx/");
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("err", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("QQQQQQQ", "finish");
```

By the way, I'm try to connect to SAM broadcaster.

Thanks:)

Comment: https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/esesem/source/browse/trunk/SSM/src/ssm/display/PanelUtama.java?r=4

Comment: sorry, I can't get you?
Where should i set up my ip?